# Bootstrap 4 .container + .row with 100% height inside flex, different results

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need to make `.left` and `.right` **at least** 100% height of the page height. I added `.h-100` (`height: 100%`) to `.container` and `.row`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bajx2mdd/3/).

IE 11, Firefox, Edge works like a charm:

[image]

However in Chrome:

[image]

Is this a know bug? How can I solve it?

**EDIT**: closed as duplicate but the original question doesn't state a clean a answer. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bajx2mdd/27/), solved adding `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1` to `.main` and `.container-fluid`.

Comment: Kindly add you Markup.

Comment: The main problem here is when combine `height: 100%` (`h-100`) with flex elements not having a height set, which won't work. As the dupe suggest as one of its the solutions, use nested flex elements all the way and remove the `h-100`.

Comment: The edit you made, nesting Flexbox, is very well showed in the dupe link's accepted answer, section _"4. Nested Flex Containers (recommended)"_. And if you understand the well explained logic in the answer, you don't need a cleaner answer. Am also sure you already know we don't add our own "(solved)" to a questions title, nor an answer within the same.

Comment: @LGSon my question is tailored bootstrap and containers/rows/columns with flexbox, hence the anwer from the other question isn't well suited.

Comment: Then out of curiosity, if to be tailored Bootstrap, why do you use Flexbox properties and not Bootstraps built-in Flexbox classes?

Comment: Furthermore, ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: @LGSon in order to create a sematic grid, have a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mixins. In addition there are no bootstrap classes for, example, flex-glow.